# Highcharts 3.0, area chart with stacked and unstacked series - how to fix?

Tags: highcharts, area

I have a complex area chart, which uses some stacked and some unstacked series.

Prior to version 3, everything worked fine.
With version 3, there are some odd buggy behaviors, in both firefox and chrome:
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yj3FP/

```
stacking:'normal',
```

If I disable stacking, everything looks as expected. But I need stacking.
So, if you comment out the 'stacking:normal' line, you will see the chart as it should be, except for the stacking part...

In the example linked to above, if you hide all of the area series except for the 'predicted' series, you will see things looking how they should.  Notice that the big thick line bordering the 'predicted' series is gone - it shouldn't be there in the first place! that line is all of the other stacked series, which do not extend along the x axis into the area of the 'predicted' series, wrapping up and over the 'predicted' series.

Now, having hidden those stacked area series, show them again - notice the very bizarre way the line twists and zig zags....

I realize this is a complex explanation. It is difficult problem to explain :)

So the question is:

1) What is going on here??

2) How do I make it stop??  :)

The issues on github are listed as solved, but I am still having the exact same issue with this chart.

Comment: Same issue reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646108/highcharts-stacked-area

Comment: Probably it is realted with known bug https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1651

Comment: Do you use master version of highcharts? which includes fix?http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js

Comment: I hadn't been, because I thought the fixes were put in as part of the 3.0.1 release.  But with the master branch, the problem is still there: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yj3FP/4/  I set it up so that the stacked area series are all hidden by default.  the chart looks as it should (minus the missing series).  Click any hidden numbered series in the legend to see the odd behavior.  Hide the 'predicted' series, and then show the other hidden series....they behave normally with the predicted series hidden.  This is all new behavior since version 3.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, solution:

I had been setting the stacking:normal at the series level in the plotoptions, and disabling it on a series by series level as needed.

I have instead removed the stacking setting from the plot options, and instead only set it on a series by series level as needed.

Problem went away.

Comment: Hi. Can you share a fiddle so we can see the code? Would be very helpful!

Comment: Sure. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yj3FP/5/  All I did was *not* specify stacking in the plotOptions, and instead only specify on the series that need it.