# highcharts stacked area

Tags: highcharts

So I think I may have encountered a Highcharts bug in terms of stacked area:

[JSFiddle Highcharts Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dRL6t/2/)

In this example, the "Social" has a start point before the "Online Video" and seems to render the points of the stacked areas erratically. If you were to deselect the charts from left to right, and then select them from right to left, the charts will render correctly. Has anyone else encountered this?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
"xAxis": [
    {
        "name": "Date",
        "unitType": "DATE",
        "title": {
            "text": null
        }
    }
],
"yAxis": [
    {
        "name": "Currency",
        "unitType": "CURRENCY",
        "title": {
            "text": null
        }
    }
],
"series": [
    {
        "yAxis": 0,
        "xAxis": 0,
        "data": [
            {
                "x": 1329724800000,
                "y": 9523.873333333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1330329600000,
                "y": 12646.573333333334
            },
            {
                "x": 1330934400000,
                "y": 12028.853333333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1331535600000,
                "y": 14016.48895104895
            },
            {
                "x": 1332140400000,
                "y": 16497.35533466533
            },
            {
                "x": 1332745200000,
                "y": 17799.29238095238
            },
            {
                "x": 1333350000000,
                "y": 21495.82333333334
            },
            {
                "x": 1333954800000,
                "y": 20261.55833333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1334559600000,
                "y": 22963.80833333332
            },
            {
                "x": 1335164400000,
                "y": 20498.47333333335
            },
            {
                "x": 1335769200000,
                "y": 23846.87499999998
            },
            {
                "x": 1336374000000,
                "y": 26080.86166666669
            },
            {
                "x": 1336978800000,
                "y": 25838.83666666667
            },
            {
                "x": 1337583600000,
                "y": 25501.14666666666
            },
            {
                "x": 1338188400000,
                "y": 23663.95
            },
            {
                "x": 1338793200000,
                "y": 31292.4716666667
            },
            {
                "x": 1339398000000,
                "y": 32823.2983333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1340002800000,
                "y": 33355.595
            },
            {
                "x": 1340607600000,
                "y": 35104.4816666667
            },
            {
                "x": 1341212400000,
                "y": 32984.61190476187
            },
            {
                "x": 1341817200000,
                "y": 34481.88142857143
            },
            {
                "x": 1342422000000,
                "y": 35663.83
            },
            {
                "x": 1343026800000,
                "y": 39744.7383333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1343631600000,
                "y": 37313.0559523810
            },
            {
                "x": 1344236400000,
                "y": 38950.5057142857
            },
            {
                "x": 1344841200000,
                "y": 43884.575
            },
            {
                "x": 1345446000000,
                "y": 43548.8683333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1346050800000,
                "y": 45227.9250000000
            },
            {
                "x": 1346655600000,
                "y": 38555.2130952382
            },
            {
                "x": 1347260400000,
                "y": 46228.5085714285
            },
            {
                "x": 1347865200000,
                "y": 50614.2016666666
            },
            {
                "x": 1348470000000,
                "y": 50058.0150000000
            },
            {
                "x": 1349074800000,
                "y": 53320.6133333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1349679600000,
                "y": 49347.0885714286
            },
            {
                "x": 1350284400000,
                "y": 49264.8047619050
            },
            {
                "x": 1350889200000,
                "y": 54185.2733333332
            },
            {
                "x": 1351494000000,
                "y": 55563.9733333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1352102400000,
                "y": 55708.3243786982
            },
            {
                "x": 1352707200000,
                "y": 48733.7656213019
            },
            {
                "x": 1353312000000,
                "y": 58758.0033333332
            },
            {
                "x": 1353916800000,
                "y": 61759.9366666667
            },
            {
                "x": 1354521600000,
                "y": 63097.59
            },
            {
                "x": 1355126400000,
                "y": 62201.8799999998
            },
            {
                "x": 1355731200000,
                "y": 54752.3342857144
            },
            {
                "x": 1356336000000,
                "y": 64890.0257142858
            },
            {
                "x": 1356940800000,
                "y": 69159.9916666666
            },
            {
                "x": 1357545600000,
                "y": 69436.6916666667
            }
        ],
        "name": "Online Video",
        "unitType": "CURRENCY",
        "type": "area"
    },
    {
        "yAxis": 0,
        "xAxis": 0,
        "data": [
            {
                "x": 1328515200000,
                "y": 47191.90571428572
            },
            {
                "x": 1329120000000,
                "y": 34517.37428571429
            },
            {
                "x": 1329724800000,
                "y": 29077.13374999999
            },
            {
                "x": 1330329600000,
                "y": 31860.52625
            },
            {
                "x": 1330934400000,
                "y": 33656.41
            },
            {
                "x": 1331535600000,
                "y": 29916.92209424082
            },
            {
                "x": 1332140400000,
                "y": 28745.66540575918
            },
            {
                "x": 1332745200000,
                "y": 33738.3710714285
            },
            {
                "x": 1333350000000,
                "y": 31722.8264285715
            },
            {
                "x": 1333954800000,
                "y": 31198.835
            },
            {
                "x": 1334559600000,
                "y": 33476.54857142855
            },
            {
                "x": 1335164400000,
                "y": 33601.01892857145
            },
            {
                "x": 1335769200000,
                "y": 30943.41749999996
            },
            {
                "x": 1336374000000,
                "y": 30949.72500000004
            },
            {
                "x": 1336978800000,
                "y": 34241.68125
            },
            {
                "x": 1337583600000,
                "y": 30031.54875
            },
            {
                "x": 1338188400000,
                "y": 29886.5087500001
            },
            {
                "x": 1338793200000,
                "y": 34003.4012499999
            },
            {
                "x": 1339398000000,
                "y": 32008.1424999999
            },
            {
                "x": 1340002800000,
                "y": 31957.5975000000
            },
            {
                "x": 1340607600000,
                "y": 33813.8885714286
            },
            {
                "x": 1341212400000,
                "y": 33055.4214285715
            },
            {
                "x": 1341817200000,
                "y": 30489.5225000001
            },
            {
                "x": 1342422000000,
                "y": 30702.0503571428
            },
            {
                "x": 1343026800000,
                "y": 32966.3821428571
            },
            {
                "x": 1343631600000,
                "y": 29196.9012500001
            },
            {
                "x": 1344236400000,
                "y": 32688.0837499999
            },
            {
                "x": 1344841200000,
                "y": 33855.33
            },
            {
                "x": 1345446000000,
                "y": 28549.045
            },
            {
                "x": 1346050800000,
                "y": 30542.815
            },
            {
                "x": 1346655600000,
                "y": 32192.9671428571
            },
            {
                "x": 1347260400000,
                "y": 30028.8653571429
            },
            {
                "x": 1347865200000,
                "y": 28983.9975
            },
            {
                "x": 1348470000000,
                "y": 32102.2757142857
            },
            {
                "x": 1349074800000,
                "y": 34292.6042857143
            },
            {
                "x": 1349679600000,
                "y": 31773.625
            },
            {
                "x": 1350284400000,
                "y": 32021.5964285715
            },
            {
                "x": 1350889200000,
                "y": 32087.5610714285
            },
            {
                "x": 1351494000000,
                "y": 29137.7275
            },
            {
                "x": 1352102400000,
                "y": 32548.594404145
            },
            {
                "x": 1352707200000,
                "y": 34536.862738712
            },
            {
                "x": 1353312000000,
                "y": 32442.137857143
            },
            {
                "x": 1353916800000,
                "y": 30339.53125
            },
            {
                "x": 1354521600000,
                "y": 32420.4666071429
            },
            {
                "x": 1355126400000,
                "y": 32267.5671428571
            },
            {
                "x": 1355731200000,
                "y": 30140.21625
            },
            {
                "x": 1356336000000,
                "y": 31462.2751785714
            },
            {
                "x": 1356940800000,
                "y": 35181.4085714286
            },
            {
                "x": 1357545600000,
                "y": 32100.06375
            },
            {
                "x": 1358150400000,
                "y": 30464.51625
            },
            {
                "x": 1358755200000,
                "y": 32761.15
            },
            {
                "x": 1359360000000,
                "y": 30037.86625
            }
        ],
        "name": "Social",
        "unitType": "CURRENCY",
        "type": "area"
    },
    {
        "yAxis": 0,
        "xAxis": 0,
        "data": [
            {
                "x": 1327910400000,
                "y": 71932.20333333334
            },
            {
                "x": 1328515200000,
                "y": 71015.56999999998
            },
            {
                "x": 1329120000000,
                "y": 64489.10809523810
            },
            {
                "x": 1329724800000,
                "y": 59054.29357142863
            },
            {
                "x": 1330329600000,
                "y": 59434.56785714285
            },
            {
                "x": 1330934400000,
                "y": 60617.94047619045
            },
            {
                "x": 1331535600000,
                "y": 57584.68013972055
            },
            {
                "x": 1332140400000,
                "y": 61606.9281936127
            },
            {
                "x": 1332745200000,
                "y": 55198.8326190476
            },
            {
                "x": 1333350000000,
                "y": 60385.3257142858
            },
            {
                "x": 1333954800000,
                "y": 54881.3528571429
            },
            {
                "x": 1334559600000,
                "y": 50847.6321428571
            },
            {
                "x": 1335164400000,
                "y": 50746.7521428572
            },
            {
                "x": 1335769200000,
                "y": 46697.2161904761
            },
            {
                "x": 1336374000000,
                "y": 48913.2923809524
            },
            {
                "x": 1336978800000,
                "y": 48944.0592857142
            },
            {
                "x": 1337583600000,
                "y": 49093.3221428572
            },
            {
                "x": 1338188400000,
                "y": 47704.8195238095
            },
            {
                "x": 1338793200000,
                "y": 49798.9383333334
            },
            {
                "x": 1339398000000,
                "y": 43637.2907142858
            },
            {
                "x": 1340002800000,
                "y": 46993.1742857142
            },
            {
                "x": 1340607600000,
                "y": 36354.43
            },
            {
                "x": 1341212400000,
                "y": 45646.7442857143
            },
            {
                "x": 1341817200000,
                "y": 38892.2640476190
            },
            {
                "x": 1342422000000,
                "y": 40631.3088095237
            },
            {
                "x": 1343026800000,
                "y": 36735.4161904764
            },
            {
                "x": 1343631600000,
                "y": 38958.0166666666
            },
            {
                "x": 1344236400000,
                "y": 33788.2871428572
            },
            {
                "x": 1344841200000,
                "y": 35576.4728571428
            },
            {
                "x": 1345446000000,
                "y": 33276.48
            },
            {
                "x": 1346050800000,
                "y": 32337.60
            },
            {
                "x": 1346655600000,
                "y": 27020.6400000002
            },
            {
                "x": 1347260400000,
                "y": 31333.0899999998
            },
            {
                "x": 1347865200000,
                "y": 28894.44
            },
            {
                "x": 1348470000000,
                "y": 30565.8733333333
            },
            {
                "x": 1349074800000,
                "y": 28436.5023809525
            },
            {
                "x": 1349679600000,
                "y": 23404.8109523810
            },
            {
                "x": 1350284400000,
                "y": 25939.9719047618
            },
            {
                "x": 1350889200000,
                "y": 22661.6014285714
            },
            {
                "x": 1351494000000,
                "y": 20579.0985714286
            },
            {
                "x": 1352102400000,
                "y": 22585.2552906402
            },
            {
                "x": 1352707200000,
                "y": 18785.2475665026
            },
            {
                "x": 1353312000000,
                "y": 19557.5735714284
            },
            {
                "x": 1353916800000,
                "y": 18670.1550000002
            },
            {
                "x": 1354521600000,
                "y": 15432.11
            },
            {
                "x": 1355126400000,
                "y": 18287.7600000002
            },
            {
                "x": 1355731200000,
                "y": 12086.7666666666
            },
            {
                "x": 1356336000000,
                "y": 13091.7819047619
            },
            {
                "x": 1356940800000,
                "y": 10996.8747619046
            }
        ],
        "name": "Affiliate",
        "unitType": "CURRENCY",
        "type": "area"
    }
],
"plotOptions": {
    "line": {
        "type": "lineOptions",
        "stacking": null
    },
    "area": {
        "type": "areaOptions",
        "stacking": "normal"
    },
    "column": {
        "type": "columnOptions",
        "stacking": "normal"
    }
},
"title": {
    "text": null
},
"chart": null
 }
);
```

Comment: This appears to relate to my issue here as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621253/highcharts-3-0-area-chart-with-stacked-and-unstacked-series-how-to-fix

Comment: Probably it is related with known bug https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1651

Answer (score -2):

I also have rendering problems with Stacked Area in `Highcharts`

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qrbzg/4/

Will contact their support team now.