# Highcharts dynamic stacked area

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an highcharts dynamic chart, I had it as a type spline and it would update dynamically fine, however when I switch too type: area and stacking: normal, the chart isn't getting stacked when it updates dynamically. On initial loading of the data the chart is fine, however when it does it after that, it just goes back to the odd charting type.

Maybe I need to set something extra for the area stack to work? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Probalbly in the plotOptiosn you has defined type of object which is stacked (i.e column) so you need to replace it with series.

See example http://jsfiddle.net/4u9sn/

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
```

Update action

```
$('#update').click(function(){
            $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){
                serie.update({
                    type:'area'
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I might have found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646108/highcharts-stacked-area, I'm trying to update the chart as a live feed, but it doesn't look like the stack area updates correctly. Thanks again though.

Comment: In my extampls it is updated dynamically, anyway hope that all works proeprly ;)